# How to correct changes to my app made by an xcode freak-out?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I have an xcode project for an app I am in the middle of developing. Recently I saved my xcode project, and then moved a single button using the arrow keys, somehow causing xcode to crash. Several re-opening attempts failed, as I saved just prior to the crash, and xcode would then simply crash upon opening.

After restarting the computer to no avail, I opened the project in xcode 5 developer preview, didn't upgrade the app to xcode 5, and then was able to open it in xcode 4 again. However, for some reason a bunch of IULabel I had created with important text were missing. After closer inspection, I found that I had some UITextFields that were also missing. When I inspected the connection in my header file, I could right click the outlet and select the UITextField. It turns out the X coordinate was set to -345, so it was missing because it was out of my view.

I suspect all of my missing UILabels are similarly out of my view, but since they aren't explicitly connecting to my header, I have no way of selecting them manually, and I can find any way of searching for them or selecting them, since they are out of my view.

Does anyone know how I might be able to select these missing UILabels so that I can change their faulty X coordinates?

Thanks!

Comment: Weird, never heard of this. Interesting.

Comment: And frightening.. Imagining this happening to a 20 screen project, during final testing..

Comment: that's why professionals use source control (and backup)

Comment: Version control and data backups.

Comment: If nothing else, the xibs are just XML so you can go through them and reset all the coordinates (or all that look fishy) manually.

Comment: Yes, it is frightening, especially since this somehow affected two of my apps! Thank god it didn't scramble any of my finished apps currently in the app store!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All UI elements you have used in your storyboard/xib should be available in the left sidebar of the interface editor.

If the sidebar is not visible you have to click the little round button at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! never clicked on that one before... I could see all of my UILabel and adjust their X coordinate to bring them back into existence. Thanks!